# Уплывает иконка в BottomAppBar

Tags: android, android-studio

При использовании BottomAppBar столкнулся с проблемой, что иконка, заданная в **navigationIcon** уплывает куда-то вверх
[image: скриншот]
Ввожу в верстку так:

```xml
 <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu"
        app:hideOnScroll="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" >
    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось, что нужно было сменить основную тему приложения на "**Theme.MaterialComponents**" и перенести BottomAppBar в **ConstraintLayout**.
[image: screenshot]